# c# Web API JSon combine Objects into Single Property

Tags: c#, json, sql-server, object, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a Web API in C# and am getting my data from a SQL Database. When I put a single student number in the GET call, their data is return correctly, however if they have two rows in the SQL query, then Return in the GET call shows their data in two separate properties. Is there a way to combine List Objects for a user who has two different rows of data into one single return. For instance, the below User belongs to two departments (Politics and Religions), and when I call the GET method, they appear twice, once for each Department;

```
{
    "roles": [
        [
            "STUDENT",
            "UG",
            2,
            "Politics",
            "Smith, John",
            123456
        ],
        [
            "STUDENT",
            "UG",
            2,
            "Religions",
            "Smith, John",
            123456
        ]
    ]
}
```

What I would like to be return is this;

```
{
    "roles": [
        [
            "STUDENT",
            "UG",
            2,
            "Politics",
            "Religions",
            "Smith, John",
            123456
        ]
    ]
}
```

I am retrieving the data from a SQL Server DB via a query, and have created a list to which I am adding the data from the query as Objects. When I search for a student using their ID, and if they have two different departments, I'd like for the 2 properties to be returned as a single one.

I have attempted the below, but this is as far as I've gotten;

```
int howmanyrecords = studentList.Count;
            if (howmanyrecords >1)
            {

                foreach(Object stu in studentList)
                {

                    var firstObject = studentList.ElementAt(0);
                }
            }
```

The above studentList.ElementAt(0) retrieves the first instance in the studentList i.e. the entry which has Politics as the department, but I'm not sure how to complete the above and how to merge into one object - my initial thought is, to compare all the indexes of both Objects and if they're different, add the value at Index X from Object2 into Object1.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code you want

```
    var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
    var roles = (JArray)jObj["roles"];
    if (roles.Count() > 1)
    {
        jObj["roles"] = new JArray(roles[0].Union(roles[1]));
        json = jObj.ToString();
    }
```

IMHO this code you need

```
    if (roles.Count() > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < roles[0].Count(); i++)
        {
            if (roles[0][i].ToString() != roles[1][i].ToString())
            {
                var arr = new JArray();
                arr.Add(roles[0][i]);
                arr.Add(roles[1][i]);
                roles[0][i] = arr;
            }
        }
        roles[1].Remove();
        json = jObj.ToString();
    }
```

output

```
{
  "roles": [
    [
      "STUDENT",
      "UG",
      2,
      [
        "Politics",
        "Religions"
      ],
      "Smith, John",
      123456
    ]
  ]
```

UPDATE

This will be working for any number of students

```
    var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
    var roles = (JArray)jObj["roles"];

    if (roles.Count() > 1)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < roles[0].Count(); j++)
        {
            var jArr = new JArray();
            for (var i = 1; i < roles.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (i == 1) jArr = new JArray { roles[0][j] };
                jArr.Add(roles[i][j]);
            }
            var arr = jArr.Distinct();
if (arr.Count() > 1) roles[0][j] = new JArray(arr); // ["Politics", "Religions"]

 //or if you dont  want an array
 if (arr.Count() > 1) roles[0][j] = string.Join(",", arr); // "Politics,Religions"
        }

        var c = roles.Count();
        for (var i = c - 1; i > 0; i--)
            roles[i].Remove();
            
        json = jObj.ToString().Dump();
    }
```

Comment: Serge, thank you for coming to the rescue for the second time this week, haha! You're becoming somewhat of a savior! I tried your solution, and it works as you advised, so thank you. Only question I have is, if it's a case of a student having more than 2 departments, say 3 or more, then how best would you say I should implement that, as the current solution works under the assumption that there'll only ever be 2 departments...which is entirely my fault as I should've been clearer in my question.

Comment: @GBM I have 2 solutions . What solution does work for you?

Comment: Oops, apologies - the second solution is the one I went with and works for me - thank you :). Let me try out your edited solution for any number of students. Thank you for taking time to help Serge. Appreciate it!

Comment: @GBM Now you will need a solution to deserialize it to your Student class. Post a question including a Student class and I will answer

Comment: Hi Serge, as requested, question now posted here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75499269/c-sharp-web-api-merge-elements-into-single-elements

Comment: @GBM You have to accept this answer at first. I vouted againt you new question since it doesn't make any sense for me, at first you told me that you selelected the second solution. You really needs to decide what do you want and think for one step ahead. What are you going to do after you droped several records in one big garbage pile. How do you know is it religious, or it is a department or name?

Comment: Religions is the department name. In the source SQL query, the student is retrieved from the Database with three departments, because they're on a Joint Programme, so they're retrieved with 3 departments. Hopefully it makes more sense in the new question I have posted. I will close this one.

Comment: @GBM I am sorry, but it doesn't make any sense, or you will have to leave the property names, not just values as it is now, or  in order to define a property name later, values should be placed in a special order. In this case if a record has several the same properties, they should be posted into brackets.

Comment: Unfortunately, the external company who will be retrieving the data from out API have been very specific about how they want the data presented, and we have tried to make them understand the complexities involved in their request but with no luck. But not to worry - I will try and figure it out. Thank you so much for your help so far with this tricky issue. Much appreciated.

Comment: @GBM I updated my answer, if you don't want an array use it  if (arr.Count() > 1) roles[0][j] = string.Join(",", arr);

Comment: bingo! That's done exactly what I wanted it to do. You sir, are a genius! Thank you so much - I used your answer from your last 'UPDATE' above! Thank you Serge :)